# UITextField keyboard difference between simulator and real device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, keyboard, uitextfield

I am trying get float value with UITextField.
On the simulator V3.1.3 in English, I have to use '.' to separate my float values.
But on my Iphone 3GS V3.1.3 in French, I have to use ',' to separate them.
If I use '.' on my Iphone 3GS, my float is troncated : 3.22222 => 3.0000000

Is there a solution to detect the language version and use the good separator automaticaly?

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the documentation for `NSNumberFormatter`. You should find what you need there.